# Допустимое сочетание слова "услуги" с другими словами

Tags: словосочетания, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли сочетать слова "Услуги по" со словами "оборудование, техника" или возможно только сочетание с существительными, обозначающими действие, например "обслуживание, монтаж и т.п."? И каким правилом тогда это регулируется?

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к другим ответам. Слово *услуги* может сочетаться с существительными в родительном падеже, обозначающими тип услуг.

- Услуги связи ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0&all=x))

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

- услуги переводов
- услуги связи
- услуг интернет-трейдинга
- услуги лизинга
- услуги аренды
- услуги выезда на дом (замерщика-курьера)
- услуги культуры

Answer (score 1):

**Услуги  связаны с действием,** поэтому слово обычно **сочетается  с отглагольными существительными.**  Даже коммунальные услуги по отоплению, водоснабжению или услуги связи предполагают **обеспечение** отоплением, водоснабжением, связью.

Поэтому можно сказать: **Услуги по обслуживанию оборудования, техники, но нельзя сказать: услуги по оборудованию, технике.**

**УСЛУГА,** -и; ж. 1. **Действие,** приносящее помощь, пользу другому. Дружеская у. Оказать услугу соседу. Просить об услуге. Помнить о сделанной услуге. 2. только мн.: услуги, услуг. **Работа, выполняемая для удовлетворения чьих-л. нужд, потребностей, при обслуживании кого-л.** Предлагать свои услуги.

**Обоснование для употребления слов** нужно искать в толковых словарях или словарях грамматической сочетаемости, но не в правилах.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как нужно эти слова сочетать. Можно, например, так:

> Услуги по оборудованию техникой.

Если же что-то делается с оборудованием, то да, в сочетании с общим для перечисления заголовком "**Услуги по**..." нужно указывать на рекламируемое *действие* (это содержание услуги - что мы *делаем*):

> Услуги по *предоставлению (по ремонту, монтажу)* оборудования и
>   (бытовой) техники.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, подскажите, пожалуйста, правило, дающее обоснование для такого ответа? ведь, наверное, есть такое?

Answer (score 0):

Слово *услуга* (в значении *поддержка*, *помощь*) включено во многие устойчивые формы: взаимные У.; коммерческая У.; коммунальные У.; лизинговая У.; медвежья У.; оказать У.; предоставлять У.; рынок У.; бюро добрых У.

Зависимые от него члены предложения отвечают на вопросы: кого?, кому?, в чём?, по чему?, за что?

Возможны сочетания «Услуги в (по) продаже *оборудования*, *техники*)» и «Услуги по *оборудованию* (т. е. проведению, производству работ)».